# Spring-Data-JPA - How to delete child record in OneToMany relationship

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a `Person` entity which has `Set<Address>` with OneToMany mapping.

```
@OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "person",
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL
)
private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();
```

Address class has

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
private Person person;
```

Now I am able to add records in the DB successfully.

How can I achieve the clearing the address hashset should result to removing the address records for the person.

For ex: In my service layer, below code does not remove the addresses in the DB.

```
Person p =  personRepository.findBy(1).get();
p.getAddresses().clear();
personRepository.save(p);
```

What is the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to do this to make this work.

```
@OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "person",
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
)
private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();
```

Answer (score 4):

orphanRemoval attribute handles child entities removal with parent entity.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="class", 
           cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE}, 
           orphanRemoval=true)
Set<ClassStudents> students;
```

OR

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="class", 
           cascade= CascadeType.ALL, 
           orphanRemoval=true)
Set<ClassStudents> students;
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you want to remove a child from the parent class you should do this by deleting the record of your child class.
In this instance you would delete the addresses in the addressRepository:

```
Person p =  personRepository.findBy(1).get();
addressRepository.deleteAll(p.getAddresses());
```